# Relationships combine two table data

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables in my database **Orders** and **OrderItems** and Order table  have One To Many relationship with OrderItems.. every order can have many items..now i need to fetch all active orders with their items from OrderItems table. for example if I have 2 active order then I want to get two order with items.. I mean I want them to combine so in my view I can loop through orders then item of that order.

This is how I am retrieving now

```
    $user_id = Auth::User()->id;

    $Orders  = Order::where([['id_email', '=', $user_id],['paid', '=', 1],])->get();

    $items   = Order::where([['id_email', '=', $user_id],['paid', '=', 1],])->orderitems;
```

But this way order does not have items inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to combine anything you could simply get the orders :

```
 $orders = Order::where('id_email',$user_id)->where('paid',1)->get();
```

Then loop through them and get the items of every one :

```
foreach($orders as $order){
    $order->orderitems();
}
```

**NOTE :** The `orderitems()` method should be defined in you `Order` model like :

```
public function orderitems()
{
    return $this->hasMany('OrderItem');
}
```

Hope this helps.